# create-react-app dependency version issues with React 18

Tags: npm, create-react-app, dependency-tree, react-18

`npx create-react-app my-project` results in the following dependency errors:

*npx version: 8.5.0*

```
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-18@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

The command still produces a project directory, but running `npm start` in the created directory errors with `web-vitals` missing from `node-modules`.

#### Solutions tried

- Running the same command with `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` as suggested by the above error message doesn't solve the problem.
- Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and running `npm i` also doesn't solve the problem.

#### Update

The problem has been fixed with the latest update of `create-react-app`. Now it creates a project without any problem.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Can you still repro?

Comment: @DanAbramov Could you write an official answer please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Until this is fixed for now you can delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json`. Next, open `package.json` and change
`"react": "^18.0.0"` & `"react-dom": "^18.0.0"` to an earlier version e.g:
`"react": "^17.0.2"` & `"react-dom": "^17.0.2"`.
Finally, you can run `npm install`.

**Alternative Solution (Try this first!):** 
solution suggested by [joooni1998](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12269#issuecomment-1095746716)):

1. delete both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. run `npm i web-vitals --save-dev`
3. run `npm install`

and then you can use `npm run build` and `npm start` again

Comment: Any idea on what's causing the underlying issue? Seems to be a webpack config. (I'm having the same issue).

Comment: I tried Gavriel's solution. The downloaded node-modules are missing web-vitals. Does someone have any idea why create-react-app can result in missing dependencies?

Comment: @DigiFreeze I think the issue is being cause by a recent merge they did to the "react-testing-library". They changed it to only supports React < 18. You can read more [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12269) & [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/pull/1041)

Comment: it didn't worked for me

Comment: @hayata_suenaga try running `npm i web-vitals --save-dev` if it gives out the error : 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-vitals''

Comment: If it is case even after 6 month, we have to downgrade to ` "react": "^17.2.0", "react-dom": "^17.2.0", "react-scripts": "5.0.0"`

Answer (score 7):

Check [here for the Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12278).

Here is a temporary workaround:

- Install cra-template to a separate folder (other than your new
  project app's folder) using "npm install cra-template"
- Go to the installed cra-template package folder and in file "template.json" change the line '"@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0"' to '"@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0"'
- Go back to your root folder and run npx create-react-app my-app (your app name) --template file:PATH_TO_YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE

Additionally, you can let the build fail, remove the node_modules folder as well as the package-json.lock file. Open the package.json file and change the react and react-dom to an earlier version.

For example:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Delete reportWebVitals.js
Remove `import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';` from index.js
Remove `reportWebVitals();` from the bottom of index.js

Finally run npm install

Comment: Thank you! Can confirm this works for the typescript template (the name of the package is cra-template-typescript). I didn't have to remove reportWebVitals either.

Comment: I wanted to take the custom templating approach but when I run "npm install cra-template" in a different directory I get the following message "up to date, audited 4 packages in 1s" but nothing is installed in that directory. There is no template.json to modify. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: `react`, `react-dom`, `@testing-library/react` - which of the mentioned packages is the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by deleting both 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json' file. Then, I changed both react and react-dom version to 17.0.2 instead of 18.0.0 inside the package.json file as suggested by Gavriel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71836018/12490294. Then, inside the app folder, I ran

```
    npm i web-vitals --save-dev
```

Then

```
    npm start
```

The app started successfully

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this `npx --legacy-peer-deps create-react-app my-appname` or goto index.js and remove the usage of web vitals

or downgrade npm with `npm install -g npm@8.3.0` and create react app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `yarn add create-react-app your-app` instead

Answer (score 0):

Been over a year since this was asked, and in spite of the suggestion by OP that it's been fixed in new versions of `create-react-app`, it still hasn't been. Also, downgrading react in `package.json` didn't work. Had to take the risk and run the command with `--legacy-peer-deps` before I could get my app working.

Answer (score -2):

Try running either with --force or with --legacy-peer-deps, both will install dependencies without problems.

If that doesn't work, then delete the node modules folder and start installing from scratch