# setting up a React Sandbox for beginners...dependencies error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Basically spent half a day trying to set this up with no luck.

I have been using `npx create-react-app` like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6P86uwfdR0&t=49s) but I receive the following:

```js
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: testfile@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
 broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!                                         the root project
```

I have seen here [create-react-app dependency version issues with React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835697/create-react-app-dependency-version-issues-with-react-18?newreg=76383a832f9d467a91df9603f112a798) that there may be dependency issues. I have tried the following fix from the post:

- delete both node_modules and package-lock.json
- run `npm i web-vitals --save-dev`
- run `npm install`
- and then you can use `npm run build` and `npm start` again

But I am still receiving error messages. I also uninstalled node.js and installed v16.14.2.

Any help would be really appreciated...

Many thanks

Comment: Yesterday I tried remaking files 5 or 6 times and all had the same issues. Today I deleted the file and made a new one (npx create-new-app .) npm start) and its working! Bizarre but i'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're already in a folder that have `package.json` file which messes things up with dependencies.

Try to begin again in a new fresh folder.

The second thing you can try is to upgrade `@testing-library/react` by using this command :

`npm install @testing-library/react@latest`

#### Why ?

As you can see on you dependencies you have a React version > 18 that's what "^" mean in `react@"^18.0.0"`

BUT `@testing-library` is requiering a reatc version that is strictly inferior to `18.0.0` that's what mean the "<" in `react@"<18.0.0"`

##### More on dependencies semantics : [HERE](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning)