# Error occured while creating a react app and unable to start the react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I am newbie to react technology and I faced an error while creating a react app:

```
Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nahee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-12T12_46_13_743Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
```

As a result I am unable to start the app

For this I used `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and `npm cache verify` commands to clear the error even though I am unable to resolve it.

For creating a react app I used

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

What is my issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app dependency version issues with React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835697/create-react-app-dependency-version-issues-with-react-18)

Comment: I used this command 'npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue with `react-testing-library`. Based on the error message, it supports only React < 18 version. You can read it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12269).

For an alternative solutions, you can manually add those to your project like how they mentioned on the error log(which I did for myself)

```
npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
```

Or you can check this too.
[create-react-app dependency version issues with React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835697/create-react-app-dependency-version-issues-with-react-18/71836328)