# Django and React version error issues when using materials library

Tags: reactjs, django, dependencies

So i'm following a video on youtube that shows how to make a music controller using django and react.
While installing the different packages for react I ran into this issue: [log file for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTy3H.png)

the exact command that is throwing the error is this:

*npm install @material-ui/core*

I tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835697/create-react-app-dependency-version-issues-with-react-18), but nothing worked for me.

can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.